# React router redirect not working when in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect

I am attempting to redirect on clicking an item, however the redirect doesn't seem to render...

```
const doRedirect = () => {
    console.log('redirecting');
    return <Redirect to='/my-path' />;
}

return <div onClick={() => doRedirect()}>Click me</div>;
```

When I click the div, it is hittin the console log just fine, however I can't seem to get it to return the redirect...

Comment: Is there any reason why you're trying to use react router that way? I strongly suggest you take a look at [useHistory](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook and how you can use it to navigate between pages

Comment: `<Redirect to='/my-path' />` will only work if it actually gets _rendered_.

Comment: You can check here on how to redirect programmatically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router

Answer (score 2):

```
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'

const history = useHistory(); 
const doRedirect = () => {
    console.log('redirecting');
   history.push('/your-path')
}


return <div onClick={() => doRedirect()}>Click me</div>;
```

The way to do this is with the useHistory hook.

Comment: Ah! You are correct! I had seen things mentioned around the history and useHistory in my search, however I mistakenly thought this was a React hook like useEffect, not something witih the react-router-dom library!